# Issue when trying to play media file using android.media.MediaPlayer and SurfaceView?

Tags: android

I am trying to play a **.mp4** file using the **android.media.MediaPlayer** class.I am trying it out on the **emulator**.Unfortunately all i see is a blank screen when running the application.

I have placed the file testmp4 in the folder **mnt/sdcard/**

Here is the code that i am using.Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
package com.mediaplayer;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MyPlayBack extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        SurfaceView surface=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
        SurfaceHolder holder=surface.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        holder.setFixedSize(400, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/testmp4.mp4");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<SurfaceView
 android:id="@+id/surface"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**:Lately i found that when I keep the application running for a long time.I see the blank white screen.But when i press the back button I can see that the frame of the video clip for a sec before the application closes.I think that the **video is playing behind** the white screen.How to bring it upfront.

Comment: Why do you not use VideoView? http://www.androidpeople.com/android-videoview-example

Comment: Try on a real device, the emulators suck for video playback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why re-invent the wheel? Use VideoView, it is meant for that. If you want to see how to see it right, look at the [VideoView source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/VideoView.java).

Also, emulators are no-good for using video. Use a real device for video application development / testing.

Comment: Thanks.I will look into the VideoView and getback

Comment: Yup, in his case I guess it is enough to use just the VideoView, but if you wanna play just the video's music (while activity not visible) and then open the activity to show and resume the video at the position of the mediaplayer, you will also need to work with the surfaceholder to set the display back (mediaplayer.setDisplay(surfaceholder) in surfaceCreated and surfaceChanged and mediaplayer.setDisplay(null) in surfaceDestroyed).
But in both cases: SurfaceView is not needed, cuz it is really reinventing the wheel :)